# Facebook .NET SDK -> Get and Post using generated token

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am writing a Azure Service that will occasionally write to my facebook page as a status.  Since the service does not have a UI component, a majority of the examples on the Facebook and Facebook .NET SDK pages are not helpful.

I created an application on facebook and then fired up the F# REPL in Visual Studio.  I generated the token like so:

```
#r "../packages/Facebook.7.0.6/lib/net45/Facebook.dll"
#r "../packages/Newtonsoft.Json.7.0.1/lib/net45/Newtonsoft.Json.dll"

open Facebook
open Newtonsoft.Json

type Credentials = {client_id:string; client_secret:string; grant_type:string;scope:string}
let credentials = {client_id="859968674039398";
                   client_secret="XXXXXXXXXX";
                   grant_type="client_credentials";
                   scope="manage_pages,publish_stream,read_stream,publish_checkins,offline_access"}

let client = FacebookClient()
let tokenJson = client.Get("oauth/access_token",credentials)
type Token = {access_token:string}
let token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(tokenJson.ToString())
```

A token comes back as expected.  However, when I go to use the token, I am getting errors:

```
let client' = FacebookClient(token.access_token)
let me = client'.Get("me")
```

returns

> An active access token must be used to query information about the
>   current user.

and

```
let pageId = "/me"
type FacecbookPost = {title:string; message:string}
let post = {title="Test Title"; message = "Test Message"}
let postResponse = client'.Post(pageId + "/feed", post)
```

returns

> The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

When I read the docs, they talk about getting the application to be approved by Facebook -> but that makes no sense in my use case b/c there is no application as defined with a human end user -> or even any other user invoking the code.

When I generate the token on [Facebook Graph Api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) with the correct permissions, I can use the token to make those GETS and POSTS.  Should I just generate the token and stick it in my .config file?  How long does a token last?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you haven't fully understood how Facebook API works.

1. You always need an App to perform an action (in your case the APP is 859968674039398)
2. In order to post on behalf a user, you will need that user to grant permissions to your App.
3. Your App has to be public and if you require more permissions than the basic ones, you need to go through the review process.

The access token you get from the Graph API Explorer (which is an App BTW) is only for you.

Please read the docs CBro provided.

I hope it helps.